# Display collection length in a view in Marionette.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I'm learning Marionette.js and have a scenario, where my app has:

```
app.addRegions({
    main: '#omen',
    newItem: '#addnewitem',
    counter: '#counter'
});
```

These regions. I have these Model/Collections:

```
var Item = Backbone.Model.extend(),
Items = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Item,
    url: 'api/items'
}),
```

I have an Item view and Items view:

```
ItemView = Mn.ItemView.extend({
    tagName: 'tr',
    template: '#itemView',
    events: {
        'click #btnDeleteBook' : 'deleteItem'
    },
    deleteItem: function() {
        app.trigger('item:delete', this.model);
    }
}),
ItemsView = Mn.CollectionView.extend({
    tagName: 'table',
    childView: ItemView,
    onShow: function(view) {
        TweenMax.staggerFrom($(view).find('td'), 1, {
            x: 100
        }, 2);
    }
}),
```

I have an initializer function, that listens for events above and does stuff through app.ItemController. It all works fine.

But now I want to add a region (counter region), that displays the total number of items in my collection. I need this to be a separate view ideally, because I will be displaying it in different places.

So I do this:

```
DisplayCounter = Mn.ItemView.extend({
    template: _.template('Total: '+ app.Items.length),
}),
```

`app.Items` is an instance of `Collection` declared above. But even before instantiation of `DisplayCounter`, I get error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined.

Please help... :(

------------------------- E D I T ----------------------

I've achieved it, but it seems to be so complicated to do such a tiny thing.

Changed my collection like so:

```
Items = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: Item,
        url: 'api/items',
        initialize: function() {
            this.listenTo(this, 'add', function() {
                app.trigger('collection:updated', this);
            });
        }
    }),
```

and changed my DisplayCounter like this:

```
DisplayCounter = Mn.ItemView.extend({
        template: _.template('Total: <%=length%>'),
        templateHelpers: function() {
            return {
                length: this.lengthVariable || 0
            }
        },
        initialize: function() {
            app.on('collection:updated', function(params){
                this.lengthVariable = params.length;
                this.render();
            }.bind(this));
        }
    }),
```

I can't believe there's no easier way to do this.. :/

Answer (score 1):

The code that sets up `DisplayCounter` is being run before the code that puts an instance of `Items` into `app.Items`.

Even if you avoided this problem by assigning `app.Items` first, you'd still have a problem - the `template` property is only set once so you'd only ever see the length of `app.Items` at the time that you define `DisplayCounter`.

Rather than hard-coding the value directly into the template string, you should supply a value at render time. `Mn.View.serializeData` allows you to customise the data that is passed into the template function at render time:

```
DisplayCounter = Mn.ItemView.extend({
  template: _.template('Total:: <%= itemCount %>),

  serializeData: function() {
    return { itemCount: app.Items.length }
  }
}),
```

Comment: oh that's useful thanks! however, my `app.Items.length` comes up as 0 and I think this is because I am using fetch() method to get Items from the server. And when the view is rendered, it doesn't have items yet. So should I implement something like `collection:change` event somewhere and then trigger an event that will say 'hey, the collection has been updated, wanna re-render?' sort of thing... ?

Comment: Yes, you should re-render in response to the add and remove events.

Comment: I've updated the code. Is that a correct way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

app.Items is not being defined.

In Marionette you can define which collection or model are your views going to use.

```
ItemsView = Mn.CollectionView.extend({
tagName: 'table',
childView: ItemView,
collection: myItems // An instance of your collection
onShow: function(view) {
    TweenMax.staggerFrom($(view).find('td'), 1, {
        x: 100
    }, 2);
}
}),
```

So marionette is going to render one itemView per element in your collection. Then inside of your collection view `this.collection` is going to refer to the collection instance. So `this.collection.length` will have what you need.

And in your `ItemView` you can get the corresponding model by using `this.model`

Comment: CollectionView is not a problem as I am passing the collection to it anyway. My problem is with DisplayCounter view...